# Latex Not Compiling

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I am working a report file. The latex file worked earlier. However, I had to reinstall latex . Now the its not compiling.

The following is the code I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1/chapter1}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranBSTCTL}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}
\end{document}
```

I am getting following error

```
I couldn't open auxiliary file chapter1/chapter1.aux ---line 2 of file main2.aux : \@input{chapter1/chapter1.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no \citation commands---while reading file main2.aux -- IEEEtran.bst version 1.13 (2008/09/30) by Michael Shell. -- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/ -- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information. Done. (There were 2 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

What could be the issue. Thanks

Comment: Do you have R/W rights to the folder `chapter1`?

Comment: How do i know that. Most importantly, the code was working earlier. But I had to reinstall OS and all apps. After that, it is not working. However, IEEE papers are compiling .

Comment: Do you have the `admin` rights to your system?

Comment: The issue is when I am using include {file} it does not work. But the same programe works when I include the content of the {file} into main file.